# Node js Telegram Чтение сообщений

Tags: node.js, npm, telegram

Есть ли способы (библиотеки) для telegram, чтобы читать входящие сообщения от бота (или любые входящие)?

Допустим я подписываюсь на бота с рассылками новостей и по приходу нового сообщения я бы смог обрабатывать что-то такое:

```
telegramClient.on('newMessage', function(client, message) {
   // вывод входящего сообщения
   console.log('Сообщение от: ' + client + ' / "' + message + '"');
   // Сообщение от: Василий Пупкин / "здарова блин"
});
```

Comment: Если именно node.js то [вот](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) (Бот АПИ), а свежих библиотек для работы с MTProto на нем нет... Есть на php, python...

Comment: Так это для создания бота я понимаю? Мне ведь нужно из клиентского телеграма (входя по номеру) доставать входящие сообщения.

Comment: MTProto? Сейчас поищу.

Comment: Смотреть в [этом](https://github.com/enricostara/telegram-mt-node/tree/master/test) направлении, если именно принципиально на node. Но она устарела.

Comment: https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto

Comment: Все как то очень сложно, я думал есть варианты по проще (как ваш аналог с ботом). Не ужели никто не делал клиент телеграма на node js?

Comment: Может и делали, но они явно не отличаются простотой использования. Есть прекрасная библиотека для работы с MTProto на PHP (я не сторонник php, но библиотека хорошая)

Comment: Разве это для Node js?

Comment: Да, это будет работать на nodejs. В папке examples есть [пример](https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto/blob/develop/examples/init.js).